# show $k<2^m$ if $2^{2^m}+1=\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

let $m$ be give positive integer,and $n,k$ be positive integer ,such $n\ge 2k\ge 2$,and
$$2^{2^m}+1=\binom{n}{k}$$

show that: $k<2^m$

Some of my ideas and attempts:
$$\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{k}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{k-1}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{1}\right)\ge (1+\dfrac{n-k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}})^k\ge\left(1+\dfrac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}\right)^k\ge 1+\dfrac{k^2}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}$$
at last two step use Holder inequality and  Bernoulli’s inequality

so we have
$$2^{2^m}\ge \dfrac{k^2}{\sqrt[k]{k!}}$$Now, I can’t prove it $k<2^m$

Comment: You have to use that $n\ge 2k$ somewhere, because if this condition is dropped, the claim is false. Also, where did you get this problem?

Comment: Hint : Every prime factor of $2^{2^m}+1$ must have the form $k\cdot 2^{m+2}+1$

Comment: @peter,Hello,then How prove it?

Comment: Bounty for this? But you nearly completed it yourself!
$$\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=\\
\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{k}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{k-1}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{n-k}{1}\right)>2\cdot2\cdot ...\cdot2=2^k$$
and $$2^{2^m}+1>2^k \Rightarrow 2^{2^m}\ge2^k$$
Remark: use the fact that for integers $a>b \Rightarrow a-1\ge b$.

Comment: @rtybase,Nice, but how to prove $k<2^m$? not $k\le 2^m$

Comment: @msexkac It's not hard to modify rtybase's approach to show that for $ k \geq 3$, ${n\choose k } > 2^{k+1} $ because of the last term $1+(n-k)$. $\quad$ EG For $n = 6, k = 3$, we get $ ( 1 + 3/3) ( 1 + 3/2)(1+3/1)  > 2 \times 2 \times 4 $. $\quad$ Hence $2^m > k$.

Comment: @Calvin,Nice !+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k = 1$, clearly, $k < 2^m$.

In the following, assume that $k \ge 2$.

We have, for all $q > k \ge 0$,
$$\binom{q + 1}{k} = 
\frac{(q + 1)!}{k! (q + 1 -k)!} = \frac{q!}{k! (q - k)!} \frac{q + 1}{q + 1 - k}
\ge \binom{q}{k}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\binom{n}{k} \ge \binom{2k}{k}.$$

Using Mathematical Induction, it is easy to prove that, for all $k \ge 2$,
$$\binom{2k}{k} > 2^k + 1.$$
(*Note*: Use $\binom{2k+2}{k+1} = \binom{2k}{k}\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2} > 2\binom{2k}{k}$.)

Thus, we have
$$\binom{n}{k} > 2^k + 1.$$

Thus, we have
$$2^{2^m} + 1 > 2^k + 1$$
which results in
$k < 2^m$.

We are done.